# Kotlin multiplatform project depending on another one with cocoapods

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, cinterop

I have a kotlin multipltform library which has several cocoapods

```
cocoapods {
    ....
    pod("gRPC/GRPCCore", grpcVersion)
    pod("gRPC-ProtoRPC", grpcVersion)
    pod("Protobuf", "3.15.8")
    // etc
}
```

I published this library to artifactory (maven) and the ios target contains all the klib's for the cinterop'ed pods.

I have a second Kotlin Multiplatform Library where I wish to consume the previous "core" library.

```
    iOSTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "SecondSharedLib"
                export("first.shared.lib:1.0.0")
                xcf.add(this)
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api("first.shared.lib:1.0.0")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting
    }
```

When linking ios however the pod modules are not found.

ex: `ld: framework not found gRPC_ProtoRPC`

I also tried redeclaring the pods to no avail.

Is what I am trying to do even possible? does anyone have any suggestions?

Note: I am not an iOS developer so please be harsh if my understanding is off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone dealing with a nested multiplatform library where the base library relies on the cocoapods plugin, I had to link all the frameworks via the linker opts as well as redefine all the cocoapods so that the frameworks would be available for linking.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42250 for more details

Answer (score 0):

have you tried below code instead when referencing another KMM project? Below code snippet is from [Kotlin's documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-add-dependencies.html#dependency-on-another-multiplatform-project)

```
kotlin {
  sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
    implementation(project(":some-other-multiplatform-module"))
  }
  sourceSets["androidMain"].dependencies {
    //platform part of :some-other-multiplatform-module will be added automatically
  }
}
```

Comment: I am essentially doing the same thing except referencing the multiplatform library from maven.